# Input in database failure

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password, Lastname, Email) VALUES
    ('$hash', '$lastname', '$email', '$email')";

  mysqli_query($MyConnection, $sql);

  if(!mysqli_query($MyConnection, $sql)) {
    echo 'We are sorry, there are some problems with saving your data. Please try again within a few minutes.';
  }
  else {
    echo 'We have succesfully saved your data. An activation e-mail will now be send to the e-mail address that you
      have provided us.';
  }
```

I get no direct errors as due to mistyping or misusing a function. I do get however the message of the if-statement in a failure, the "We are sorry(..)" text.

There must be a problem with the execution of the mysqli_query($MyConnection, $sql) function. But I don't see where it is.

P.S. I can't post images, because my reputation is below 10. (Which is quite weird to limit it to that point)

As some of you have provided most / all of the code:

```
<?php

  // Opens the connection of the MySQL Database
  $MyConnection = mysqli_connect('fdb6.biz.nf', '1446018_amp', '-') 
         or die("Could not connect to the database, please try again");
  mysqli_select_db($MyConnection,'Users');

  mysqli_connect_errno();

  // Website Url:
  $website = 'http://www.askmephilosophy.co.nf/';

  // Information provided by the user
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];   // Will get encrypted.
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  // A higher "cost" is more secure but consumes more processing power
  $cost = 5;

  // Create a random salt
  $salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');

  // Prefix information about the hash so PHP knows how to verify it later.
  // "$2a$" Means we're using the Blowfish algorithm. The following two digits are the cost parameter.
  $salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;

  // Hash the password with the salt
  $hash = crypt($password, $salt);

  $sql= "INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password, Lastname, Email) VALUES
    ('$hash', '$lastname', '$email', '$email')";

  mysqli_query($MyConnection, $sql);
  var_dump(mysqli_error($MyConnection));

  if(mysqli_query($MyConnection, $sql)) {
    echo 'We have succesfully saved your data. An activation e-mail will now be send to the e-mail address that you
      have provided us.';
  }
  else {
    echo 'We are sorry, there are some problems with saving your data. Please try again within a few minutes.';
    mysqli_error($MyConnection);
  }

  mysqli_close($MyConnection);

?>
```

Comment: You're executing the query twice. If you have some restraints on any of the columns, it will throw an error. You also declare four columns, but only send three values.

Comment: Try placing the result in a variable and checking from that instead. `$query = mysqli_query($MyConnection, $sql);` then `if ($query === false) {`

Comment: Even when commenting out / removing the first mysqli_query function, and remove the '!' mark in the if-statement, changing the display messages whether it failed or not, it still gives me the error.

Comment: @JesseDijkstra - echo out `mysqli_error($MyConnection)`, and you can see why the database call is failing.

Comment: Please provide us with your table structure and a sample data you are trying to insert for better help

Comment: I'd love to, but I can't post any images to the comments / discussion itself. As my reputation is below 10.

Comment: Your connection info still looks weird... So your database is Users and the table your trying to insert records into is Users??? Seems like you may be mistaking the table Users as the Database name or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you only have 3 values, it doesn't match the number of items you are trying to Insert (4) ...

```
 $sql= "INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password, Lastname, Email) VALUES
('$username', '$hash', '$lastname', '$email')";
```

**EDIT:**

I would probably write it like this

```
 $sql= "INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password, Lastname, Email) VALUES
    ({$username}, {$hash}, {$lastname}, {$email})";
```

**EDIT:**
Your password cannot be '-'

I would update your connection info like so:

```
$db = new mysqli('fdb6.biz.nf', 'user', 'pass', 'Users');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

**EDIT AGAIN:**

```
    $myConnection = new mysqli('fdb6.biz.nf', 'user', 'pass', '1446018_amp');
    $myConnection->mysqli_select_db($MyConnection,'Users');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password, Lastname, Email) VALUES
('$hash', '$lastname', '$email')";
```

This is your first issue; your table has four columns, and you're passing it three. This query is guaranteed to fail.

```
mysqli_query($MyConnection, $sql);

if(!mysqli_query($MyConnection, $sql)) {
```

You're calling the query function twice. You can do this with a single call:

```
if(!mysqli_query($MyConnection, $sql)) {
     // add some error handling code here
     // store the return value of mysqli_error() somewhere
     echo 'We are sorry, there ar....';
```

Since you're using mysqli_, you should also be using prepared statements; I hope at least you're sanitising the database inputs before you try to add them to the database.

Comment: I agree that they should be using prepared statements to prevent SQL Injection, good catch.

Answer (score 0):

try adding, I think you forgot this. Values always have to equal to columns

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password, Lastname, Email) VALUES
('$username', '$hash', '$lastname', '$email')";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are inserting twice that records, as there are two instances of `mysqli_query($MyConnection, $sql);`. You can just remove the first.

The problem here is that you are inserting 3 values in 4 fields.

Anyway you can get the specific error with

```
mysqli_error($MyConnection);
```

Add it at the end your echo forever or `var_dump(mysqli_error($MyConnection));` in a new line.

Comment: It is still not working, and I get no error message with the mysqli_error($MyConnection);

Comment: @JesseDijkstra - what do you get if you try `mysqli_query($MyConnection, $sql); var_dump(mysqli_error($MyConnection);`?

Comment: I get an error: "string(20) "No database selected" I'm gonna look into that.

Comment: But behind the mysqli_connect() function I wrote:
"or die("Could not connect to the database, please try again");"

Comment: `mysqli_connect` will connect you to the database _server_. You then need to tell it what database to use with `mysqli_select_db()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: That's it. Or you can specify the database as the fourth parameterm in mysqli_connect() - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Answer edited with the useful var_dump.

Comment: I've tried to put the 4th parameter on the table 'Users' but it even gives me more errors. I've a port, and a friend told me I have to do nothing with it. While in your link the port is noticed. Am I doing things wrong? Because it somehow doesn't give errors on the connection, yet it won't save the information in the table.

Comment: $sql= "INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password, Lastname, Email) VALUES
    ('$hash', '$lastname', '$email', '$email')"; You have Username first and password second, then two emails. That's probably not what you want. Again, you are doing mysqli_query($MyConnection, $sql); twice.